# How to setup virtualenv in atom editor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, virtualenv, atom-editor

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up a virtual env in atom. I tried installing `atom-python-virtualenv` and I'm trying to use `configure script`, but it still says "no virtualenv" at the bottom of the atom editor. How can a select or make a virtualenv for atom?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to make the environment from Atom itself but you can make your virtual environment from the command line by typing

> conda create -n myenv python=3.6

where 3.6 can be changed to whatever version you have installed and myenv is a name for your environment. You then activate the environment by typing

> conda activate myenv

Now you can run Atom from this environment. Directions concerning virtual environments are [located here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and [here](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)